# How can I get HTML syntax highlighting in my editor for CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, syntax-highlighting, notepad++, aptana

I use Notepad++ and Aptana for editing my CakePHP code? Is there any way to get basic html syntax highlighting for CakePHP's .ctp template files? It's a lot harder for me without any coloring going on. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks guys! I had tried that before, but I must have missed something really dumb :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Configuring in Aptana Editor**

> Quoted from aptana docs

1. From the Window menu, select
   Preferences..., and then choose
   General > Editors > File
   Associations.
2. Add the appropriate file type.
3. Next to the File Types list, click
   the Add button.
4. In the New File Type pop-up window,
   type the appropriate file extension
   (e.g. "*.ctp" or "*.thtml").
5. Click OK to add the New File Type to
   the List.
6. Associate the new file type with
   Aptana.
7. On the File Types list, select the
   file type that you just added.
8. Next to the Editor Associations
   list, click the Add button.
9. On the Editor Selection pop-up
   window, select the editor that you
   want to associate with your file
   type.
10. Click OK to add the editor.
11. The new is now associated with the
     specified file type.
12. Click OK to apply your changes and
     close the Preferences window.

***Check out this [link](http://www.aptana.com/docs/index.php/Using_Aptana_with_PHP,_ASP,_and_other_non-HTML_files)***

Answer (score 1):

You probably just have to select Language -> Html in the menu bar. You can set the association in Settings -> Style Configurator -> Html

Answer (score 1):

Settings -> Styler Configurator -> Language: HTML -> User ext: ctp

done :-)

Answer (score 0):

Another little tip that I picked up on.....to get some basic syntax completion in Aptana:

1. Right Click on your Projects, Select Properties
2. Goto the "Project Natures" tab and make sure that the PHP component is clicked (If not you will have to click it, close the properties window and reopen it)
3. Next we're going to click on "PHP Buildpath" and select the "External Folders" tab
4. Add the location of a plane jane CakePHP install

Let Aptana re-profile the project and viola....you have some syntax completion. It's not perfect....but it's better than nothing!