# Disable syntax errors for PHP code inside JavaScript file in Aptana Studio 3

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, aptana, aptana3

I am having PHP code inside my JavaScript file, which is processed by the server by setting the handler for the .js file extension to `php5-script` using a `.htaccess`. I tried opening the .js file in Aptana Studio using PHP Source Editor and JavaScript Source Editor, however, both editors highlight the php code as syntax error. I couldn't find an option in the settings where I can set the file type to a mix of PHP and JavaScript, or disable syntax error highlighting for PHP code in JavaScript, or anything else.

I have found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19235742/disable-syntax-error-highlights-on-php-code-in-a-js-file-phpstorm) but this is just related to the PHPStorm IDE which I do not want to use.

The content of my .js file currently looks like this:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/javascript');

$app_base_path = $_GET['_app-base-path'];
$app_route = $_GET['_app-route'];
?>

$(function() {

    var APP = {

        // syntax errors are thrown here
        // the single quotes could be escaped to reduce syntax errors
        // looking for a way to make a code like this possible without any syntax errors
        base_path: '<?= $_GET['_app-base-path'] ?>',
        route: '<?= $_GET['_app-route'] ?>'

    };

    $('body').append('APP.base_path: ' + APP.base_path + ' --- APP.route: ' + APP.route);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I previously read your question wrong.  My bad.  If php is NOT parsing the `<?= ?>` tags, make sure it's enabled in php.ini

Unless the string data in the `$_GET` parameters contain strings with single quotes in them, you shouldn't have an issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, sorry for my late reply. I think i formulated my question wrong: I want to stop my editor (Aptana Studio) marking these two PHP code parts as error or syntax error highlighting them.

Comment: Ah!  OK!  That makes sense, was a little confused there.  You know, you could have it as a .php extension rather than a .js extension and then in your htaccess just point the .js extension to the php extension and that would take care of your syntax error issue.

Comment: Well, then I could also just open the .js file with Aptana's PHP Source Editor.. However this doesn't solve my problem,  because then the javascript code is not syntax highlighted.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/811656/how-can-i-get-html-syntax-highlighting-in-my-editor-for-cakephp

Comment: Other than that unless there's a way to add syntax highlighting to a file extension, I think it's something someone with a lot more experience with Aptana should be helping you out with.  I'm a PHPStorm, PyCharm, RubyMine guy.  Personally, I'd go with my suggestion and just add something like .js.php to the extension so you know it's a .js file with php and edit it with your php editor instead.

Comment: Yes, I had a look at it. This doesn't help me since this would only let my apply a specific editor to a file type. What I would need is applying a mix of the PHP Source Editor and JavaScript Source Editor to my .js file.

Comment: The problem when renaming the file to .php extension is that I get not syntax highlighting for JavaScript code in there. Well, I think I have to keep coding with either the black JavaScript code or the PHP syntax error highlightings. However, thanks for your help.

Comment: Might I offer one more suggestion: Language Injections with PHPStorm would take care of this for you https://confluence.jetbrains.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=53315225

Comment: I would like to stay in Aptana since I'm developing with it for years now, but I think I have to give PHPStorm a try. Thanks for your suggestion ;)